# Rename and Deleting Elasticsearch Indexes

Tags: elasticsearch, rename, alias, nest

I'm using C# .NET application with NEST to create an index.

I've created an elasticsearch index that customers can query called index_1. I then build another version of the index using a different instance of the application and call it index_1_temp.

What is the safest way for me to rename index_1_temp to index_1 then delete the original index_1?

I know ES has aliases but I'm not sure how to use them for this task

EDIT: The original index does not have an Alias associated with it.

Comment: I just read about Client.Swap in NEST but the version I'm using doesn't have that (it's been depreciated I believe)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would recommend always [using aliases](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/index-aliases.html) in scenarios where you may create incrementally differing versions of an index, as may be the case when refining the model of signals within your search strategy.

You can add an alias at the point of creating an index

```
var client = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);

var indices = new[] { "index-v1", "index-v2" };
var alias = "index-alias";

// delete index-v1 and index-v2 if they exist, to 
// allow this example to be repeatable
foreach (var index in indices)
{
    if (client.IndexExists(index).Exists)
    {
        client.DeleteIndex(index);
    }
}

var createIndexResponse = client.CreateIndex(indices[0], c => c
    .Aliases(a => a
        .Alias(alias)
    )
);
```

Then when you create a new index, you can remove the alias from current indices and add it to the new index. This alias swap operation is atomic

```
createIndexResponse = client.CreateIndex(indices[1]);

// wait for index-v2 to be operable
var clusterHealthResponse = client.ClusterHealth(c => c
    .WaitForStatus(WaitForStatus.Yellow)
    .Index(indices[1]));

// swap the alias
var bulkAliasResponse = client.Alias(ba => ba
    .Add(add => add.Alias(alias).Index(indices[1]))
    .Remove(remove => remove.Alias(alias).Index("*"))
);

// verify that the alias only exists on index-v2
var aliasResponse = client.GetAlias(a => a.Name(alias));
```

The output of the last response is

```
{
  "index-v2" : {
    "aliases" : {
      "index-alias" : { }
    }
  }
}
```

When searching, the consumers would always use the alias. Since the alias points to a single index only, you can also use it to index new documents and update existing documents.

Comment: Hi Russ. Thanks for your detailed reply, I'll probably implement a version of this. The only tricky issue I have is that the index is already created (without an alias) so all of the requests going to the index use just the index name. I guess I could create a new alias, add it to the original index then re-write the code so it querying the index refers to the alias rather than the index name?

Comment: Yes, that sounds like a reasonable approach. You then have the flexibility to change the ind[ex/ices] that the alias points to

Comment: Elasticsearch should call this a Pointer or Label. I feel like Alias doesn't properly explain this.