# Nest - Point Alias to new index

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have multiple indices, sets say `index_test1` and `index_test2`. The newest index should always have an alias called `the_alias`. Creating this alias is pretty easy with

```
client.CreateIndex("index_test3", d => d
    .Mappings(ms => ms ...
    .Alias(a => a.Alias("the_alias"))
);
```

But now the alias does not disappear on the other indexes but points to multiple ones.

When I create a new index I want to remove the alias from the old index but I don't know the name of the old index, how can I do this?

In other answers I saw stuff like `Client.Swap` but `ElasticClient` does not have that method.

Comment: Which version of NEST and Elasticsearch are you using?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/44147111/1831. After you've created the new index, swap the alias from any existing indices to the new index.