# ElasticSearch - Filtering the type

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest

I have upgraded my elasticsearch from v1.9 to v5 and I have noticed that a lot of things have changed.

If I were to take an example from v1.9: The below code checks whether the object type matches `ObjectAdo` and it filters the items within `ObjectAdo` that have the `IsDeleted` field as `false`.

```
private Func<FilterDescriptor<dynamic>, FilterContainer> Filter()
        {
            return b => b.Bool(x => x.Must(m => m.Type(typeof(ObjectAdo)), n => n.Term("IsDeleted", false)));
        }
```

Now, after upgrading from v1.9 to v5, I noticed that `FilterDescriptor` got changed to `QueryContainerDescriptor` and `FilterContainer` is now `QueryContainer`. Now I am unable to perform the same operation as before because `.Type(typeof(ObjectAdo)` is no longer available.

So I am wondering if there is an alternative solution to check the object type.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOPex.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Elasticsearch 2.0, [queries and filters merged into one](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking_20_query_dsl_changes.html#breaking_20_query_dsl_changes), with the notion of a query context and a filter context; when wrapped in a bool query filter clause, a query/filter is in a filter context so relevance scores will not be calculated and it will be cacheable.

NEST 2.x onwards aligns with the change in Elasticsearch 2.0 and has queries (`QueryContainer`, `QueryContainerDescriptor<T>`, etc.) that can be used in both query and filter contexts.

Applying this to your filter, would mean changing it to the following with NEST 5.x

```
private Func<QueryContainerDescriptor<dynamic>, QueryContainer> Filter()
{
    return b => b.Bool(x => x
        .Filter(
            f => f.Type(t => t.Value(typeof(ObjectAdo))),
            f => f.Term("IsDeleted", false)
        )
    );
}
```

The s[yntax for a `type` query has changed a little](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/type-query-usage.html) to take a lambda expression to set available options.

Comment: I had figured out this. But thanks anyway. I am new to the elastic search concept so I was wondering how an Alias index (say: my_blog) points to multiple indices in the server like my_blog-2017-12-06 or my_blog-2017-12-09. Would be nice if you could let me know.

Comment: I have upgraded Nest and ElasticSearch.Net to v 5.0.0. I tried querying with Kibana and I get the result but when querying from my .Net application I get 0 results. I wonder what the problem could be.

Comment: @Mark - take a look at the query being sent to Elasticsearch from NEST and compare it with what is being sent in Kibana: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/troubleshooting.html. Take a look at the Index Aliases API for adding aliases to indices: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html. Here's an example with NEST: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44147111/1831

Comment: Thanks again for replying. Going to check these out.

Comment: Russ Cam, could you please take a look at this?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44601950/elasticsearch-auto-mapping

Comment: This seems to be missing in NEST 7. I don't see any `Type` method any more.