# Elasticsearch.Net - Changes after upgrading from v1.9 to v5.4

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest

I have noticed a lot of changes in ES after upgrading it from v1.9 to v5.4.

I am still having doubts about the querying techniques in ES. In v1.9 I have noticed that the Filter option differs.

I am wondering how I can replicate the below code in v5.4

```
searchDescriptor.Query(q => q.Filtered(m => m.Query(n => matchQuery).Filter(o => o.And(filterContainer.ToArray()))))
```

Here I see `Filter(o => o.And(filterContainer.ToArray())` how is it possible to do an `And` or an `Or` operation with v5.4?

Does `Filter(o => o.And(filterContainer.ToArray())` indicate that each item in the array are bound with an `And` operaton?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.And()` and `.Or()` were deprecated in Elasticsearch 2.0 and removed in 5.0. You can replace them with a [`bool` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/bool-queries.html)

- for `.And()`, if you require scoring, then used `.Must()`. If you don't require scoring, use `.Filter()`.
- for `.Or()`, use `.Should()`.

`bool` queries can be nested, so it's possible to create complex compound queries.

> searchDescriptor.Query(q => q.Filtered(m => m.Query(n => matchQuery).Filter(o => o.And(filterContainer.ToArray()))))

becomes something like

```
var matchQuery = new MatchQuery { Field = "field", Query = "query" };

var filterContainer = new QueryContainer[] {
    new TermQuery { Field = "field", Value = "value" }
};

client.Search<Message>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .Bool(b => b
            .Must(matchQuery)
            .Filter(filterContainer)
        )
    )
);
```

filtered queries were deprecated in 2.0 and removed in 5.0.

> Here I see Filter(o => o.And(filterContainer.ToArray()) how is it possible to do an And or an Or operation with v5.4?
>
> Does Filter(o => o.And(filterContainer.ToArray()) indicate that each item in the array are bound with an And operaton?

For these, pass them to a `bool` query filter clauses, which are conjunctive i.e. and'ed. If you need to `or` clauses, you can nest `bool` queries with filter clauses within a `bool` query should clauses.

Comment: Thank you. Makes a lot of sense. How about for `.Missing()` and `.Not()` does ES 5 have something new for this? Would really appreciate a reply. Thanks again.