# How to safely recreate an index with .NET client Elasticsearch

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am using Elasticsearch NEST 6.x, and in my indexer, I would like to delete the existing index and recreate a new one as my data gets updated. This is what I currently have:

```
this.elasticClient.DeleteIndex(indexName, x => x.RequestConfiguration(y => y.AllowedStatusCodes(404)));
this.elasticClient.CreateIndex(indexName, x => x.Settings(s => s.NumberOfShards(1)).Mappings(ms => ms.Map<T>(m => m.AutoMap())));
this.elasticClient.Bulk(b => b.Index(indexName).IndexMany(entities));
```

The problem with this approach is that if `delete` is successful but `create` fails, that index won't be available until it's recreated. Further, even in the best case where it succeeds, in the meanwhile the index is being recreated, all the searches to that index will fail since it does not exist. Is there a better way?

**Edit:**

I think it's worth mentioning why I *recreate* the index as @leandrojmp asked:

My data is not additive, i.e. over time, some indexed entities need to be added, some need to be updated, and some need to be removed. On the other hand, the amount of data I have is small enough that this approach sounds feasible.

However, I'm new to elastic search and would love to know if there is a better way.

Comment: What kind of problems are you expecting during creating? Do you want to inform the calling site about occured problems or just keep trying till it succed?

Comment: @Prolog I have a background task that runs every 20min, and tries to recreate the indexes. I didn't quite get how the answer to your question could make a difference here though. The CreateIndex could fail for a bunch of reasons. But, even in the best case where it succeeds, in the meanwhile the index is being recreated, all the searches to that index will fail since it does not exist.

Comment: Why are you deleting and recreating an index instead of just updating it?

Comment: @leandrojmp my data is not additive, i.e. over time, some indexed entities might get deleted (or updated/added). On the other hand, the amount of data I have is small enough that this approach sounds feasible. However, I'm new to elasticsearch, and would love to know if there is a better way.

Comment: Can you share a sample of your data and how you query it? There's not much you can do to stop your searchs from failing while the index is being created, maybe use a timestamp in the index name and only delete an index after a new one is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to consider using index aliases and

1. create versioned indices e.g. `my_index_v1`
2. create an alias that points to a single index e.g. `my_index` alias that points to `my_index_v1`
3. Use the `my_index` alias for bulk indexing and search

Then when wishing to *delete and create* the index,

1. create a new index `my_index_v2`
2. send a request to the alias API to remove the `my_index` alias from `my_index_v1` and add to `my_index_v2`
3. delete `my_index_v1`

In doing so, any applications and operations can use the index alias. With this approach, it is possible that data you intended to be indexed into `my_index_v2` is actually indexed into `my_index_v1`, because the bulk index request is processed before `my_index_v2` is created and the index alias is swapped over. If this is an issue, then you could make `my_index_v1` not writable when creating `my_index_v2` and swapping the alias over, and handle the failure to bulk index in your application, potentially queueing those documents that fail to be indexed and trying again; you might check for a specific failure response from bulk indexing, and check the index metadata to see if the index is writable.

Comment: And here is Russ's answer to another question that has some sample code on how to create the alias and swap them in C#, thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44144153/rename-and-deleting-elasticsearch-indexes/44147111#44147111